# Kendall's Tau Correlation for dataset with multiple types (binary, categorical, ordinal, continuous)

Tags: correlation, python, spearman-rho, kendall-tau, pandas

I have a dataset of many variables of varying data types (binary, categorical, ordinal, continuous), and I want to find the correlations between them. I encoded the binary as (0,1) and one-hot encoded the categorical variables. I thought that I could simply use a Kendall's tau correlation matrix because of the different types. However, when I look at the highest correlations, it seems that the (one-hot encoded) categorical variables have the highest correlations with each other.

I understand that the problem lies in the one-hot encoding, but then I have several follow-up questions to resolve the issue:

1. Should I still be using one-hot encoding? If not, how should I encode the categorical variables?
2. Should I use a Chi-square test for only the categorical variables, and is this correlation test comparable to the Kendall's Tau / Spearman's rank?
3. If I need to use different / multiple different tests, can a meaningful comparison be made between them?

After encoding, the only code I ran was:
df.corr(method='kendall') # also used 'spearman' but found the same results

Thank you for your help!

(For coding reference, I am using python/pandas, not R)